# Collision Response of ball at Corners of rectangle

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

i have a fixed rectangle. When ball hits a vertex of a triangle, i calculate tangent at point of contact(rectangle vertex). Then i rotate Velocity vector to coincide with the tangent, flip the y value of velocity and rotate it back. Here is my code for top-left corner:

```
double c1x=rec.x-ball.getX();
double c1y=rec.y-ball.getY();
if(c1*c1+c2*c2<ball.getRadius()*ball.getRadius())
    {
        double angle=Math.atan2(-c1x,c1y); //angle made by tangent
        Vector2D v=ball.velocity.rotate(angle); //rotate velocity vector by 'angle'
        if(v.y<0.0f)     //ball is already moving away from corner
            return;
        v.setY(-v.y);    //flip y
        ball.velocity=v.rotate(-angle);   //rotate back
        return;

    }
```

But this code doesnot works. When ball strikes the corner it gets stuck, moves along the top edge and then falls off, not bouncing back. Am i doing it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Making some guesses about your conventions, I suggest this:

```
double angle=Math.atan2(-c1x,-c1y);
```

If that doesn't work, we can do some experiments to figure out what's actually going on.

**EDIT:**

All right, we must build up from simpler solutions. Try these experiments:

1) Set velocity to (0,1) and verify that the ball moves straight up after the collision.

2) Set velocity to (-1,1) and verify that the ball moves up and leftward.

If those work as expected, then pick a trajectory that you would expect to behave in a normal way, such as approaching from above and to the left, then rebounding almost straight up but slightly leftward, then run it through your code *but print out all the values in the collision* and tell us what they are. That's at least `c1x`, `c1y`, `angle`, and the values of `velocity` initially and after each rotation.You'll probably notice where things go screwy, and if you don't we will.

Comment: No affect even after reversing the sign.